# Casablanca (cpprestsdk) build error on windows 8.1 using visual studio 2015

Tags: android, c++, c++11, visual-studio-2015, casablanca

**The Goal**

Use [cpprestsdk](https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk) in a basic Android app as a proof of concept.

**What I have done so far**

I have been following [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk/wiki/How-to-build-for-Android-on-Windows) wiki on github. I'm trying to build the cpprestsdk on Windows 8.1 using Visual Studio 2015.

The wiki gives some NuGet instructions and also instructs readers to apply the following project settings:

- General -> Use of STL = gnustl_static
- C++ -> Code Generation -> Enable C++ Exceptions = Unwind Tables (-funwind-tables)
- C++ -> Language -> Enable Run-Time Type Information = Yes
- C++ -> Language -> C++ Language Standard = C++11

**The Problem**

After following the NuGet instructions and applying the project settings, I get this error (amongst others):

This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.    AndroidCasablanca   C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK\android-ndk-r10e\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.9\include\bits\c++0x_warning.h 32  Build

But I have specified the C++ 11 option in the project settings. So, why doesn't it build?

Comment: Make sure you've changed settings in all of combinations: Debug/Release, ARM/x86. Check twice.

Comment: @Drop It's building now. Part of the issue was that it was not being set in all configurations. The other issue was that I was building for the wrong architecture.